Performance Impact of Partial Index on INSERTs Not Involving the Partial Match
Given:
postgres=# create table testing(a int primary key, b int not null);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# create index on testing (b) where b = 0;
CREATE INDEX
postgres=# \d testing
              Table "public.testing"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 a      | integer |           | not null | 
 b      | integer |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "testing_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (a)
    "testing_b_idx" btree (b) WHERE b = 0

When INSERT-ing a new row where b != 0, will I pay the penalty of updating the index?
Ideally I'd like to speed up queries with a value of b = 1 without adding delay to inserting new rows where b != 0.

Why you expecting a partial index where b=0 to get updated when b<>0? There won't be any index page modification when b<>0. You can verify this by checking size of partial index against a normal index.

If you insert a row where b is distinct from 0, the index testing_b_idx won't be modified, and you won't have to pay the price for the modification of the index.
To be accurate, there is a tiny overhead, because there must be a check if b is 0. But that overhead will probably not be measurable.
